# Symbols loaded (source information stripped) error when creating C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am just trying to get the think-gear test application to work, it will communicate with a mind-wave EEG through a USB radio frequency transmitter. They have a tutorial to get there test program working and i followed it completely, i copied all the correct header, DLL files and code files, and the program does run, it loads the think-gear DLL file and tests it then it waits for a key press to continue as soon as i press a key it closes and gives me this error...

```
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Users\Daniel Braithwaite\Google  Drive\Progrmamming\Quadcopter Project\EEG C++ Workspace\EEG\Debug\thinkgear_testapp.exe',       Symbols loaded.
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Users\Daniel Braithwaite\Google Drive\Progrmamming\Quadcopter Project\EEG C++ Workspace\EEG\Debug\thinkgear.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thinkgear_testapp.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The program '[6268] thinkgear_testapp.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I am running this in Visual Studio 2010 and i have tried changing the symbols setting under the debug menu, but that didn't make a difference. Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error.

Since you're running your program under a debugger, it tries to load symbols for each loaded DLL. Symbols are extra information needed to match runtime memory addresses to addresses of functions, local variables etc.

"Source information stripped" means source code information has been stripped away. You'll notice you get this message for Microsoft binaries.

You can notice you get full symbols for the code you compile yourself.